# How to not load Index.html?

Tags: html

When a website doesn't have an index.html file, the navigator displays an auto generated page right ?

[Here](https://perso.liris.cnrs.fr/nicolas.lumineau/teaching/LIFBDW1/TP/) is an example of what I mean.

This page is very handful to explore a website, but sadly it is only displayed when there is no index.html page.

Is it possible to access such a page on a website, even though index.html exists in the folder ?

I'm using Opera, but I have tried other navigators and none of the common ones seems to do what I want ^^

Thanks for reading

Comment: This is not an auto generated page. It is directory browsing of server which can be enabled/disabled through server control panel.

Comment: Or it can be disabled/enabled in the `.htaccess` file. (just put: `Options -Indexes` inside `.htaccess`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an auto generated page. It is directory browsing of server which can be enabled/disabled through server control panel (or using .htaccess in linux servers).

When you have default document (like index.html) in a folder, the server servs the default document instead of directory browsing. So if you want to let directory browsing when you have `index.html`, you have to clear the `index.hmtl` from the list of default documents. This can be done using IIS settings (if you have access to server) or through hosting control panel in website settings (in shared hostings) (or by direct editing of `web.config` or `.htaccess`)

Answer (score 1):

> the navigator displays an auto generated page

No.  This has nothing to do with the browser.  The browser displays whatever the server returns.  Nothing more, nothing less.

What you're seeing on that link is from the Apache web server.  That web server is configured to (and can be configured *not* to) return a generated directory listing when no default response can be determined.

The "default response" *might* be `index.html`, or `default.html`, or literally *anything* that the web server is configured to look for by default.  (Those are just, well, the common defaults.)

In many modern web applications the concept of a "page" doesn't even really mean the same thing, because things like MVC frameworks don't just browse directories for `.html` files but instead examine requested routes and generate responses from code.

> Is it possible to access such a page on a website, eventho index.html exist in the folder ?

No.  Because that "page" doesn't exist.  The web server returned that to you because it was configured to.  If it's not configured to then that data doesn't exist.